# Cakephp undefined index syntax

Tags: php, cakephp, syntax

I don't know why this syntax is not working.

First I like to find which customer invited (`this`). I do it with a query and use find where `user_id` => this customer id from `CustomerRel` table.

```
$refID = $this->CustomerRel->find('first', array('fields' => array('CustomerRel.refer_user_id'), 'conditions' => array( 'CustomerRel.user_id' => $this->Auth->User('Customer.user_id'))));
```

Then I am checking if status is `1`:

```
$statusOne = $this->CustomerRel->find('first', array('conditions' => array('CustomerRel.user_id' => $this->Auth->User('Customer.user_id'), 'CustomerRel.status' => 1)));

if($statusOne){
    //$referr = $refID['CustomerRel']['refer_user_id'];
    $referr = $this->Customer->findById($refID['CustomerRel']['refer_user_id']);
    $referr['Customer']['wallet_amount'] += 50;
    $this->Customer->save($referr, null, null);
    // Wallet History
    $walletHistoryFriend['amount']              = 50;
    $walletHistoryFriend['purpose']             = 'referrel credit';
    $walletHistoryFriend['customer_id']         = $this->Customer->findById($refID['CustomerRel']['refer_user_id']);
    $walletHistoryFriend['transaction_details'] = 'referell';
    $this->WalletHistory->save($walletHistoryFriend, null, null);
}
```

The thing is that I get customer id "NULL".

Comment: Do you mean that: $this->Auth->User('Customer.user_id') is NULL?

Comment: Thanks for comment.
No i actually have two issues:

$referr['Customer']['wallet_amount'] += 50;  // Here i get undefined 'Customer' and undefined 'wallet_amount'

// Here i get Null

$walletHistoryFriend['customer_id']         = $this->Customer->findById($refID['CustomerRel']['refer_user_id']);

Comment: What's the output of $referr? (var_dump)

Comment: Not sure i added var_dump($referr); before $referr['Customer']['wallet_amount'] += 50;

Then i got this: bool(false)

Comment: That means: $this->Customer->findById($refID['CustomerRel']['refer_user_id']); returns false - no matching record has been found.

Comment: Hi thanks for help :)
I have solved thank you!